# Combine multipage API results in Mathematica

Tags: import, api

*Updated to show more code*

Can't seem to find a good post/answer to this so I'm asking the question.

I'm pulling data from the Swarm/Foursquare API, and it's paged (max 250 results per pull):

```
url = StringTemplate[
    "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?startTime=`a`&\
endTime=`b`&oauth_token=`c`&limit=250&offset=`d`&v=20220406"][<|
    "a" -> startTime, "b" -> endTime, "c" -> oauthToken, 
    "d" -> offset|>];
response = Import[url, "RawJSON"];
checkins = response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]];
Until[Length[response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]]] == 0,
 offset += 250;
 url = StringTemplate[
    "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?startTime=`a`&\
endTime=`b`&oauth_token=`c`&limit=250&offset=`d`&v=20220406"][<|
    "a" -> startTime, "b" -> endTime, "c" -> oauthToken, 
    "d" -> offset|>];
 response = Import[url, "RawJSON"];
 AppendTo[checkins, response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]]]
 ]
```

I should have around 1,200 results. Instead, I have 256. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you having trouble only combining the results? Or do you need help with the logic to continue to download until there are no more results?

Comment: I updated the post to show the complete code I'm trying to use.

Comment: Figured out on my own. apparently have to go one at a time:
```
Do[
 AppendTo[checkins, 
  response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]][i]],
 {i, 0, Length[response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]]]}
 ]
```

Comment: The problem is that you are appending the subsequent result lists as a single item to your list. You need to `Join` the two lists instead, so `checkins = Join[checkins, response[["response", "checkins", "items"]]]` should do the trick

Comment: Thank you, @LukasLang, that's more efficient than what I came up with. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I have to go one at a time on the Append:

```
Do[
 AppendTo[checkins, 
  response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]][i]],
 {i, 0, Length[response[["response"]][["checkins"]][["items"]]]}
 ]
```